# Find the equation of a circle given two tangent lines, and a line passing through center

Tags: circles, plane-geometry, tangent-line

This geometry question feels like it should come very easily but alas, it isn't, so I find myself here.

I have the following information: (z) passes through my center, (s) and (r) are my tangent lines.

$$(z) 6x-7y-16=0$$
$$(r) 8x+15y+7=0$$
$$(s) 3x-4y-18=0$$

So given a circle with center ($x_0$,$y_0$) I know the distance between my center and (s) will be equal to the distance between my center and (r).

$d(C,r) = \frac{|8x_0 + 15y_0 + 7|}{\sqrt(8^2 + 15^2)} =\frac{8x_0 + 15y_0 + 7}{17} $

$d(C,s) = \frac{|3x_0 - 4y_0 - 18|}{\sqrt(3^2 + (-4)^2)} =\frac{-3x_0 + 4y_0 + 18}{5}, \frac{3x_0 - 4y_0 - 18}{5} $

$5(8x_0 + 15y_0 + 7) = 17(3x_0 + 4y_0 + 18)$

$40x_0 + 75y_0 + 35 = 51x_0 + 68y_0 + 306$

$y_0 = \frac{11x_0}{7}+\frac{271}{7}$

I substitute this into the equation of the line passing through the center and get $x_0 = 51$. However, even before I continue to operate, I can see this won't give me a correct answer as my book tells me that the two solutions end up being:

$x^2+y^2-10x+4y+28=0$

$x^2+y^2-6x+\frac{4}{7}y+\frac{324}{49}=0$

Comment: Why did the absolute values vanish?

Comment: An error I fixed now

Comment: The circles provided in the solution do not have their centers lying on the given line. Rather, they lie on $6x\color{red}{+}7y-16=0$.

Comment: Wow, thank you, that just about explains all the issues I've been having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it must be

$$\frac{|8x_0+15y_0+7|}{\sqrt{64+225}}=r$$
$$\frac{|3x_0-4y_0-18|}{\sqrt{9+16}}=r$$

$$6x_0-7y_0-16=0$$
One solution is given by
$$r=\frac{275}{74},x_0=\frac{1679}{74},y_0=\frac{635}{37}$$

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: Two Solutions will be attained

Comment: I reach that conclusion and I'm working through the system, but I seem to be making an error somewhere as I don't obtain the correct answer.

Comment: Which answer did you obtained?

Comment: Thank you so much Dr. Sonhard for your assistance. As pointed out above, there was an error in one of my equations which was the source of my confusion. I appreciate the time you've taken to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation for the line $z$ is wrong; it should be $6x+7y-16=0$. Your problem becomes$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}\frac{|8 x + 15 y + 7|}{17}=\frac{|3 x - 4 y - 18|}5\\6x+7y=16,\end{array}\right.$$whose solutions are $(5,-2)$ and $\left(3,-\frac27\right)$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I reached the correct solution. I can't believe I had that error in my equation for the line through my center! It caused quite a headache. Thank you, I've now answered the problem correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

I would suggest a different approach, noting that the circle will have the center on
the lines (there are two) bisecting the angles between $r$ and $s$.

So
 - detemine the point (say $Q$) of intersection between $r$ and $s$;
 - determine the unit vectors normal to $r$ and $s$ ($\bf n_r=(8,15)/\sqrt{8^2+15^2}$ etc.);
 - the normal vectors $\bf b_1,\bf b_2$ to the bisecting lines will simply be $\bf n_r \pm \bf n_s$: don't need to take them unitary;
 - having the normal vectors determine the lines normal to them , passing through $Q$;
 - $C_1, C_2$ will be their crossing with line $z$;
 - the radii will be the (absolute) value of the dot product of $\vec {QC_n}$ with $\bf n_r$ (or alternatively with $\bf n_s$).

Comment: Equations for the two bisectors can be constructed directly from the equations for $s$ and $r$.

Comment: @amd: you are certainly right, there shall be a direct formula, but I am not aware of that (didn't feel the need to learn by mind).